# Prevent double click in submit-button when postback from other controls executed before button click

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I got a problem in preventing double click of Submit button in `ASP.NET`. 
I can disable the submit-button in pages which don't have ASP.NET `Calendar`. 
In pages which have this `Calendar`, calendar's postback disables the submit-button before the button is clicked.

I used the following javascript to disable the button in button-click. It works if there is no postback from other asp.net-controls before the submit-button is clicked.

```
function DisableButton() {
    document.getElementById("<%=ibtnNext.ClientID %>").disabled = true;
}
window.onbeforeunload = DisableButton;
```

i don't know what to do.
All suggestions are welcome.

Comment: _"calendar's postback make 'Submit' button disable before button is clicked"_ that doesn't make much sense to me. Can you show the code that disables it?

Comment: probably meant he disabled the button on postback so any postback (which in this case caused by calendar) disabled it. 

@Myo Min Lin how are you disabling the button? client or server side?

Comment: Thanks all for comments.

i want to disable 'Submit' button after it is clicked. I used the following javascript. It works for simple page which doesn't have any postback from other asp.net controls

function DisableButton() {
            document.getElementById("<%=ibtnNext.ClientID %>").disabled = true;
        }
        window.onbeforeunload = DisableButton;

Comment: why can't you assign DisableButton() as onclick attribute for ibtnNext in pageload?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all,
i got solution now as the following

javascript
`<script type="text/javascript">
      function DisableButton(btn){
            btn.disabled = true;
      }
</script>`

in page load

```
protected sub Page_load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim optionsSubmit As New PostBackOptions(ibtnNext)
    ibtnNext.OnClientClick = "DisableButton(this);"
    ibtnNext.OnClientClick += ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(optionsSubmit) End Sub
```

in click event

```
Protected Sub ibtnNext_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.ImageClickEventArgs) Handles ibtnNext.Click
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000) End Sub
```

original link
http://www.devtoolshed.com/content/disable-button-submit-prevent-multiple-submits

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the **window.onbeforeunload** event. Disable the button on its **OnClientClick** event.

The button's **postBack(onClick event)** will get executed only after the **OnClientClick** event in javascript.

```
<button id="ibtnNext" OnClientClick="return DisableButton()" onclick="btnSubmit_Click">Copy Text</button>

<script>
function DisableButton() 
{
     document.getElementById("<%=ibtnNext.ClientID %>").disabled = true;

     return true;
}
</script>
```

Comment: thanks for suggestion, but it just disabled button, can't save data. i can use window.onbeforeunload event if there is no postback from other controls before button is clicked.